# Add a classname after form is submitted and page reloads

Tags: php, forms

Can anyone please help me on this:

I am trying to add a classname/ change the css of div using jquery; after I click submit on the form. Means, after clicking submit and when the page reloads this classname/ changes should stick to the target element. I am using php to get the values of form submitted. (no ajax, but if necessary I can modify my code). I tried to do this by jquery but when the page reloads the changes are gone !

Thanks.

**update:** Here is the sample code(so.php itself) I am working on. after form is submitted and page is reloaded; say I want to add a class to input that is clicked and manage the style in CSS:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm" action="so.php" method="get">
    <input name="Load" type="submit" value="Google" />
    <input name="Load" type="submit" value="MSN" />
    <input name="Load" type="submit" value="Yahoo" />
</form>     
<div id="container">
    <?php
        if (isset($_GET['Load'])) {
            $value = $_GET['Load'];
            echo "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"349\" src=\"http://www.{$value}.com\"></iframe>";
        }
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**update2:** I tried the logic provided by @NoPyGod and it worked. But here is the thing. I am trying to add a class to the button that is selected as well as update the text in the div with id "hello" with the value of input that is clicked or in active state once the form is submitted and page is reloaded. This is the one I ended up but once form is submitted
all the inputs are having the same class name as well the text in div is also not updated.

```
<html>
<head>
<?php if (isset($_GET['Load'])): ?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#hello').text('Hello');
    });
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm" action="so.php" method="get">
    <input class="<?php if (isset($_GET['Load'])) { echo "some_class"; } if (isset($_GET['Load1'])) { echo "some_class1"; }?>" name="Load" type="submit" value="Google" />
    <input class="<?php if (isset($_GET['Load'])) { echo "some_class"; } if (isset($_GET['Load1'])) { echo "some_class1"; }?>" name="Load1" type="submit" value="Rediff" />
    <input class="<?php if (isset($_GET['Load'])) { echo "some_class"; } if (isset($_GET['Load1'])) { echo "some_class1"; }?>" name="Load" type="submit" value="Yahoo" />
  <input class="<?php if (isset($_GET['Load'])) { echo "some_class"; } if (isset($_GET['Load1'])) { echo "some_class1"; }?>" name="Load1" type="submit" value="Sify" />
</form>

<div id="container" >
    <?php
        if (isset($_GET['Load'])) {
            $value = $_GET['Load'];
            echo "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"349\" src=\"http://www.{$value}.com\"></iframe>";
        }
        if (isset($_GET['Load1'])) {
            $value = $_GET['Load1'];
            echo "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"349\" src=\"http://www.{$value}.com\"></iframe>";
        }
    ?>
</div>

<div id="hello"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the page is submitted, set a variable like so

```
$was_submitted = true;
```

Then in your HTML do something like this

```
<div id="myid" class="<?php if ($was_submitted) { echo "some_class"; } ?>">
```

Or if you absolutely insist on using jQuery to change it, include this in your html --

```
<?php if ($was_submitted): ?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myid").addClass("some_class");
    });
</script>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Updated:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm" action="so.php" method="get">
    <input name="Load" type="submit" value="Google" />
    <input name="Load" type="submit" value="MSN" />
    <input name="Load" type="submit" value="Yahoo" />
</form>

    <!-- I changed this line below -->

    <div id="container" class=<?php if (isset($_GET['Load'])) { echo "some_class"; } ?>>
    <?php
        if (isset($_GET['Load'])) {
            $value = $_GET['Load'];
            echo "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"349\" src=\"http://www.{$value}.com\"></iframe>";
        }
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But excuse me as I am newbie to PHP. Can you tell me how to set the variable when the form is submitted

Comment: I'd need to see the code you use to handle the form submit in order to do that.

Comment: I updated the code in my original post. Please have a look and suggest me how to set a variable

Comment: I have updated my code. I can see you are quite new to all of this so I won't give you any lectures about your code, but try to read up on separating business and presentation logic.

Comment: Thanks. The code you provided worked like charm. And yes I am a newbie and trying to learn php now. I will try to separate logic. I have a doubt in your code. You added class attribute and php isset to container div but what i am trying to do is set the same to input tag and show the one that is selected. I applied the same logic you provided but once the page is reloaded all the inputs are having the same class name :(

Comment: i updated the code in update2 block. Please take a look and suggest me.

Comment: You are on the right track. But rather than checking if the variable isset, check what the variable is set to. ie.. <?php if $_GET("Load") == "MSN ....